# What's the equivalent of the container bootstrap class in purecss.io?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yui-pure-css

I'm using [purecss](http://purecss.io/) for my project.

I want to have all my content center on my page like with the bootstrap container class.

I tried to use different things using the purecss grid but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Trust only in source young Luke:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css

```
.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Only after the update of original question i realized you where referring to *Pure* framework.

I took a look at the source of the source https://github.com/yahoo/pure/blob/master/src/grids/css/grids-core.css and realized that it adds no sizing on `pure-g` which is a grid wrapper just like `container` from *Bootstrap*.

So, the *Pure* framework is more generic than *Bootstrap* and it is perfectly reasonable for you to specify the width of that container by yourself to whatever you want.

Just apply *Bootstrap* `container` rules to `pure-g` class:

```
.pure-g {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .pure-g {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .pure-g {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .pure-g {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

Comment: First block, exactly what I wanted! Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`container` value follow `Boostrap 4.4`,
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/overview/

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
} 
@media (min-width: 576px) {
    .container {
        width: 540px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 720px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 960px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1140px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.centered{
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .centered{
          margin: 0 auto;
          width: 95%;
        }
 }

 <div class="centered"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

max-width in bootstrap container

```
.container {
width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}
```